# WindowManager.LayoutParams why is there a setTitle method?

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

So yesterday i was programming and suddenly i came across the `setTitle` method in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` class, why would this class like this have a `setTitle` method? Where is is used for? The documentation does not say anything about the function.

My guess is that it could be used for debugging or something a like, but other than that i don't have a clue.

And why would it be declared as final method? Because it's not ready yet for us to override it?

Just wondering...

**Note: Both answers below are some how "correct" and offer good information, but can only accept one.**

[getTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#getTitle%28%29)

[setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going through the source code for [WindowManager](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/view/WindowManager.java.htm), it seems that the title isn't actually used anywhere, except in the debug and parcel writing methods.

Furthermore, searching google for `+"windowmanager.layoutparams" +".setTitle()" site:grepcode.com` doesn't seem to return any results where the [setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [getTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#getTitle%28%29) methods of `WindowManager.LayoutParams` are actually used in production code.

I'd say that the Android engineers felt that maybe at some point of time in the future they might need a title property, and put it in as a stub.

Comment: @Mr.Me Ah, but I didn't catch the SoftInputWindow and StatusBar Service :P nice going there.

Comment: Both answers are actually some how "correct", accepting one is what i normally would do but both answers offer different information and therefor i would need to accept them both.... thinking...

Comment: @RolfSmit Accept Mr. Me's. He actually managed to find two places where its used.

Comment: @RolfSmit still Raghv Sood found an actual usage that I didn't mention (parcel writing) and debugging

Answer (score 4):

Well There doen't seem to be any usage for this layout parameter value anywhere.

It seems like a place holder for now.

I only managed to find these tow cases where it has been used:
[SoftInputWindow](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/inputmethodservice/SoftInputWindow.java)
and 
[StatusBar Service](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/StatusBarService.java)

And visually both has no effect (at least on my device and emulator)